# Modifying Vue query with beforeEnter

Tags: vue.js

The scenario: I'm replacing one application with another - both have a /search route with potentially very long queries. The new data structure has changed considerably and, unfortunately, some URLs for the old application have been distributed elsewhere containing multiple parameters which no longer exist.

One way to deal with this might be to intercept each call to search and, by means of `beforeEnter()` modify `query` by looking up and replacing the offending terms. I'd have thought something like this:

```
{
    name: "search",
    path: "/search",
    component: Records,
    beforeEnter(to, from, next) {
        let query = hackSearch(to.query);  // replaces the old terms
        next({name: 'search', query: query});
    }

},
```

This causes `Uncaught (in promise) InternalError: too much recursion`, though. But, from what I understand of documentation and examples I've seen, this, or something like it, should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not great, but I modified `hackSearch()` so it would return whether or not it had found an offending term and replaced it. This enables the code above to be modified as follows:

```
{
    name: "search",
    path: "/search",
    component: Records,
    beforeEnter(to, from, next) {
        let [query, modified] = hackSearch(to.query);
        if (modified) {
            next({name: 'search', query: query});
        }
        else {
            next();
        }
    }

},
```